# How to document struct data members outside of struct

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

When I document a function with Doxygen I can do this:

```
/*!
 * @brief does something
 * @param a first parameter
 *
 * Longer description
 */
void foo(int a) { /* */ }
```

But is there way I can document struct members this way:

```
/*!
 * @brief a struct
 * @??? a first struct member
 * @??? b second struct member
 *
 * Longer description
 */
struct a 
{
    int a,
    int b,
};
```

The reason is, I want to avoid having to document my struct members with inline comments, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*!
 * @struct str_a
 * @brief my a struct
 * @details Longer description
 *
 * @var str_a::a
 *   @brief first struct member
 *   @details detailed first struct member
 * @var str_a::b
 *   @brief brf second struct member
 *   @details detailed second struct member
 *
 */
struct str_a
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```